# why do Linux bind mounts disappear if the mount point's inode changes?

Tags: linux, mount, inode, bind-mount

In summary: if you bind mount a file `/tmp/a` on top of `/tmp/b` in a new mount namespace, but then the inode of `/tmp/b` changes in the parent namespace, the bind mount disappears in the child namespace. I'm trying to understand why.

mount(8) doesn't expose the ability to bind mount individual files (just directories), so reproducing this requires an additional executable that can issue the necessary mount(2) syscall. Here's a simple example (referred to as `bmount` below):

```
#include <sys/mount.h>
#include <errno.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    if (argc != 3) {
        printf("requires exactly 2 args\n");
        return 1;
    }

    int err = mount(argv[1], argv[2], "none", MS_BIND, NULL);
    if (err == 0) {
        return 0;
    } else {
        printf("mount error (%d): %s\n", errno, strerror(errno));
        return 1;
    }
}
```

Set up the test case:

```
# echo a > /tmp/a; echo b > /tmp/b; echo c > /tmp/c;
# ls -ldi /tmp/a /tmp/b /tmp/c
11403315 -rw-r--r-- 1 root root 2 Jan 19 13:34 /tmp/a                                                               
11403422 -rw-r--r-- 1 root root 2 Jan 19 13:34 /tmp/b
11403452 -rw-r--r-- 1 root root 2 Jan 19 13:34 /tmp/c
```

Now, in a separate shell:

```
# unshare -m /bin/bash
# bmount /tmp/a /tmp/b
# ls -ldi /tmp/a /tmp/b /tmp/c
11403315 -rw-r--r-- 1 root root 2 Jan 19 13:34 /tmp/a
11403315 -rw-r--r-- 1 root root 2 Jan 19 13:34 /tmp/b
11403452 -rw-r--r-- 1 root root 2 Jan 19 13:34 /tmp/c
# cat /tmp/b
a
# grep "\/tmp\/" /proc/self/mounts
[redacted] /tmp/b ext4 rw,relatime,errors=remount-ro,data=ordered 0 0
```

In the original shell:

```
# mv /tmp/c /tmp/b
# ls -ldi /tmp/a /tmp/b /tmp/c
ls: cannot access '/tmp/c': No such file or directory                                                               
11403315 -rw-r--r-- 1 root root 2 Jan 19 13:34 /tmp/a                                                               
11403452 -rw-r--r-- 1 root root 2 Jan 19 13:34 /tmp/b
```

In the `unshare` shell:

```
# ls -ldi /tmp/a /tmp/b /tmp/c
ls: cannot access '/tmp/c': No such file or directory
11403315 -rw-r--r-- 1 root root 2 Jan 19 13:34 /tmp/a
11403452 -rw-r--r-- 1 root root 2 Jan 19 13:34 /tmp/b
# cat /tmp/b
c
# grep "\/tmp\/" /proc/self/mounts
#
```

The bind mount has silently disappeared, and the underlying filesystem's `/tmp/b` file is now visible inside the namespace.

I found a [lwn.net article](https://lwn.net/Articles/570338/) which describes a change in semantics here: before 2013, the `mv` command's `rename(2)` on the mount point would fail with `EBUSY`, but the behavior was changed so that it would succeed and then the mount would be removed. The relevant kernel commit appears to be [8ed936b5671](https://github.com/torvalds/linux/commit/8ed936b5671bfb33d89bc60bdcc7cf0470ba52fe).

The questions I have are:

1. Why is the mount removed on any inode change? Is it just an implementation detail of the mount system, where the mount point is identified by a dentry rather than a simple path?
2. Is there a way to make bind mounts that are less "brittle" in the sense that they can't be overridden or removed by filesystem operations outside their namespace?

One case where this is relevant in practice is [ip-netns(8)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man8/ip-netns.8.html); `ip netns exec` works by bind mounting `/etc/netns/${NAMESPACE}/resolv.conf` on top of `/etc/resolv.conf`. If the inode of `/etc/resolv.conf` is altered by resolvconf(8) or systemd-resolved, the updated `/etc/resolv.conf` will be visible to the process running inside the namespace.

Comment: I had the same issue and ended up mounting `/etc` as an `OverlayFS` directly onto `/etc`. Mount options: `index=off,lowerdir=/etc,upperdir=/path/to/overlay/dir,workdir=/tmp/somedir`.

Answer (score 5):

<del>This is mount propagation.  Linux does not enable it by default, but systemd does.  If you don't want mounts and unmounts to propagate to the new namespace, you can e.g. run `mount --make-rprivate /` inside it.</del>.  Narrator: this is not mount propagation.

> Why is the mount removed on any inode change? Is it just an implementation detail of the mount system, where the mount point is identified by a dentry rather than a simple path?

I would say that the only different you can expect between `rm b; mv c b` and `mv c b`, is that it is not possible to observe `b` as non-existent at any point.  I would describe this as a feature which has been deliberately engineered or maintained...  I'm not sure to what extent this is true of the historical multi-user Unix system, but it certainly came to be relied upon e.g. to support software updates on a running system.

I... can think of [exactly one other specific feature which has been implemented for what you call "inode change"](https://lwn.net/Articles/322823/) - this was done begrudgingly and is filesystem-specific.

Comment: FWIW, the `rename()` behavior you're referring to where it will atomically replace has been around since at least SVR4 and early editions of the original BSD, so it's pretty solidly present in historical systems too.  The behavior itself has long since been codified in POSIX (I'm pretty sure it was in the original spec) and the Single Unix Specification as a mandatory part of the VFS API.

Comment: Sorry, I'm confused: are you saying that if I run `mount --make-rprivate /` inside the `unshare -m` shell, that will stop the bind mounts from disappearing? I can't reproduce this.

Comment: Hmm, I think you're right, that part of the answer is completely wrong.

Comment: You can't stop file deletion propagating from one view of a tmpfs to another view of the same tmpfs.  It's the same tmpfs with the same files.  Except in the sense that you can hide the entire directory which contains the file you're going to delete, by overmounting it.